# req.body.data is undefined in expressjs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, body-parser

I am new to nodejs and express js. I am trying to send a json object to my nodejs app using postman. PFB my app code

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app   = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/game",function(req,res){ 
      console.log(req.body);

      console.log(req.body.gameId);
//var body = req.body;
//game.addGame(req,res,body);

});


 app.listen(setting.port);
 console.log(`The app is listening to port ${setting.port}`);
```

I send the below json object using postman

```
{
    "gameID": 4,
    "gameLevel": 3,
    "gameImage": "/3wewe/wewrw",
    "gameName": "Game2",
    "waitTimeForWinny": 30,
    "totalTime": 31,
    "orderSequence": 1,
    "maxPoints": 10
}
```

Then I got the below output in the console.

```
{ gameID: 4,
  gameLevel: 3,
  gameImage: '/3wewe/wewrw',
  gameName: 'Game2',
  waitTimeForWinny: 30,
  totalTime: 31,
  orderSequence: 1,
  maxPoints: 10 }
undefined
```

The json object is coming in the req.body. But I am not able to extract the field from it by useing req.body.gameId

Please help me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing in the id property as `gameID`, but you are logging `gameId` (note the lowercase `d`)

Comment: Thanks a lot.... that was so foolish of me... is there any good IDE for nodejs, so that I don't have to waste my time on such small issue.

Comment: I prefer JetBrains [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) (not a sponsored link, damn it, they should give me money).  I use it for all JS/TS dev work anymore